# What is R's equivalent to Matlab's subs(f, x, value) for symbolic substitution?

Tags: r, matlab, octave

In Octave, I use the following to differentiate a function of 2-variables and then substitute 0 for x using subs(). Basically in doing moment-generating-function, Taylor series expansion, etc, we differentiate and then substitute some a for x. I am not able to find the equivalent substitution function in R. Can you please let me know how to do it? Thanks

```
pkg load symbolic; #octave symbolic package
syms lamb, x; #declare lamb, x symbols
mgf = lamb / (lamb - x); #moment generating function of exponential
mgf1 = diff(mgf, x, 1); #1st differivative
mgf1_0 = subs(mgf1, x, 0); #substitute 0 for E(X)
```

Comment: your example would be a little more useful for future readers if you include the necessary package-loading and variable-defining steps ...

Comment: added pkg. look fwd to your future helps on R, which I am rather confused about in many aspects.

Answer (score 4):

Using base R:

```
f <- quote( lambda / (lambda - x) )
Df <-  D(f, "x")

do.call("substitute", list(Df, list(x = 0)))
## lambda/(lambda - 0)^2
```

or we can evaluate Df at specific x and lambda values:

```
eval(Df, list(x = 0, lambda = 3))
## [1] 0.3333333
```

### Create function to represent result

We can use `Df` to define an R function `der` which evaluates the derivative at specific x and lambda values.

```
der <- function(x, lambda) {}
body(der) <- Df
der(0, 3)
## [1] 0.3333333
```

### Currying

If we want to set x to 0 and create the resulting function of lambda

```
make_der0 <- function(x = 0) function(lambda) der(x, lambda)
der0 <- make_der0()
der0(3)
## [1] 0.3333333
```

This is known as currying or partialling and various packages have this as well:

```
library(functional)
der0a <- Curry(der, x = 0)
der0a(3)
## [1] 0.3333333

library(purrr)
der0b <- partial(der, x = 0)
der0b(3)
## [1] 0.3333333
```

Comment: Cool answer to use `quote` and `substitute`, +1!

Comment: This is nice but doesn't simplify the result. (I find it a little bit ironic that you wrote `rSymPy`, which my answer uses ...)

Comment: by the way, I'm a little confused about the development status of `rSymPy`. I posted an issue at https://github.com/cjgb/rSymPy but I'm not sure if it's current:   http://rsympy.googlecode.com looks broken ... ?

Comment: I'd be willing, but I'd only be able to do dumb R-level maintenance stuff (e.g., maintaining CRAN compliance).  If anything broke in the internals the probability I'd be able to fix it would be <0.001 ...

Comment: @BB, Have moved discussion to email.

Comment: I use eval(f,values) when substituting specific values for all symbols, but many function-to-function problems require substituting for partial symbols only. As an everyday user, R seems to make me think about how to do something as common as symbol substitution, while I can just think about what to do in Octave.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be using the `symbolic` package, which in turn depends on the `sympy` Python library.  R doesn't have built-in symbolic manipulation capabilities, but it does (TIL) have an `rSymPy` package that works similarly.

```
## https://kevinkotze.github.io/mm-tut1-symbolic/
library(rSymPy)
```

`rSymPy` doesn't have a built-in `subs()` function, so we'll define one:

```
subs <- function(expr,x,y) {
    Sym(expr,".subs(",x,",",y,")")
}
```

Also useful to define this (not sure if there's a better way):

```
r_eval <- function(s,eval_list) {
   eval(parse(text=sympy(unclass(s))), eval_list)
}
```

The rest of the code looks almost identical to the Octave code. Define variables:

```
## NOTE: 'lambda' is a reserved word in Python, so trying to use it as 
## a variable gives rise to confusing errors ...
lam <- Var("lam")
x <- Var("x")
f <- lam/(lam-x)
```

Differentiate:

```
mgf1 <- deriv(f,x,1)
```

Substitute:

```
subs(mgf1,x,0)
```

There are other interfaces from R to symbolic math engines, e.g. [Ryacas](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Ryacas).

If you want to compute the second moment by calculating f''(0), that's not much harder:

```
v <- subs(deriv(f,x,2),x,0)  ## "2/lam**2"
r_eval(v, list(lam=5))  ## 0.08
```

Comment: I have been playing with moment generating functions and taylor series expansions etc in Octave, and always relied on subs(f,x,value). I didn't expect it is such a hassle in R for a seemingly simple operation.

Comment: Well, neither platform has native symbolic computation, and I've just showed how you can do it just about as easily in R as in Octave ... I should have defined the `subs()` function first, then the code would have been pretty much identical to yours (except that you left out the package-loading and variable-definition steps ...

Comment: A similar issue when doing college math in R or Octave, can you please help shed some light on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853882/how-to-calculate-a-bayes-estimator-using-octave-or-matlab

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try package `Deriv`

```
library(Deriv)
f <- function(l,x) l/(l-x)
fprim <- Deriv(f,"x")(2,0)
```

such that

```
> fprim(2,0)
[1] 0.5
```

Comment: didn't know that package. Can it substitute x only? I see you substituting l=2, x=0, which can be done using eval(mgf1).